# About Juju charms

Tags: juju

I need td-agent charms with bionic series. Only trusty series is available in charmstore.
Please guide me how to get that charm with bionic series otherwise please inform me how series conversion happens in charm...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](https://www.fluentd.org/download), td-Agent or Fluentd is also available for Ubuntu Bionic Beaver.
You can download the suitable version for Ubuntu 18.04 via [this link](https://td-agent-package-browser.herokuapp.com/3/ubuntu/bionic/pool/contrib/t/td-agent).
Choose the version you want, and click on it to download it.
Once the download is finished, go to the download folder (let's assume it is Downloads) by running on the terminal `cd ~/Downloads` then run `sudo dpkg -i <the name of the td-agent package>` (for example `sudo dpkg -i td-agent_3.5.1-0_amd64.deb`).

For additional details and other methods of installation, check [this link](https://docs.fluentd.org/installation/install-by-deb)

Comment: Actually, I need specified charm.. Otherwise need info about how to convert series from trusty to bionic

Comment: I still didn't get what you want, what do you mean by 'specified charm'?

Comment: Actually I want to integrate td-agent bionic series charm with my bundle but it is not available in charmstore. Only trusty series charm available for the same. So, my question is how I will get td-agent charm with bionic series.

Comment: May be it would be better to contact [the publisher](https://support.treasuredata.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000763388-Support-Channels) to ask them about Bionic support.